# Magento looking for template in a wrong folder

Tags: magento

Hi I am facing problem with Magento: it can't find template file which I request on the home page with the help of this line: `{{block type="profile/profile" name="profile" template="profile/news-front.phtml"}}` but magento gives me error: `Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/profile/news-front.phtml`.

I have my `news-front.phtml` file in `frontend/default/default/template/profile/news-front.phtml` why magento doesn't see that file and how can I display my news block on the front page?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to check out [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy/).

If it won't answer your question, then as you see Magento tries to search your template in base package. 
It means that either you don't have following file in default or your theme in

```
System->Configuration->Design
```

is not 'default'.

Comment: It is `default` but still mgento looks for file in `base` folder instead of `default`

Comment: If magento does in this way it means that either file name is wrong, or it doesn't exists or there is something wrong with this file. Also check in design if there is another theme set up.